# Are Perl Websocket events atomic?

Tags: perl, websocket, atomic

There are a number of events that can be triggered in the Perl websocket server:
http://search.cpan.org/~topaz/Net-WebSocket-Server-0.001003/lib/Net/WebSocket/Server.pm

For instance, on_handshake, on_ready, on_utf8 etc. It isn't clear, however, whether these events are handled atomically. That is, if there's a shared variable used by all these events, will its state be consistent after each call?

Comment: A very simple test where I put a sleep() command into the on_utf8 event handler, where said handler uses a global variable, suggests that yes, the Websocket server IS atomic in handling events - or at least handles them sequentially as they come in.